# Clear input value and then focus

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this little issue... I'm trying to clear an input and after that I want to focus it, the problem is that I want to do this after displaying a bootbox alert message, doing this my code only clear my input text but doesn't focus it, how can I do this? Here is an [Example Code](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/xdJXwE).

I tried to solve this doing this:

```
var msj = bootbox.alert("Error message.");
$('#Barcode').val('');
msj.on('shown.bs.modal', function () {
    $('#Barcode').focus();    
});
```

The above code doesn't work for me.

**Edit: Here is my code.**

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  
  $('#Number').on('keyup', function () {
    var num = $(this).val();
    
    if (num > 0)
      console.log("nothing to do");
    else {
        bootbox.alert("Clear input and then do focus");
        $('#Number').val('');
        $('#Number').focus();
      }
      
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://bootboxjs.com/bootbox.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" />


<input type="number" id="Number" />
```

Comment: Your Codepen is broken. Also, is the `bootbox.alert` modal? If so, there's no way this can possibly work, as the focus would need to be given to the modal to dismiss it.

Comment: Your pen doesn't work. Please check these things before posting. It just wastes everyones' time. Are you sure this is correct ->> `'shown.bs.modal'` - looks a lot like bootstrap to me, but I don't know what bootbox is so might be correct

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan If I click my codepen link works properly, however I added a snippet, but I can't get my css stylesheet working properly.

Comment: `If I click my codepen link works properly` Are you sure? I get this: http://i.imgur.com/tTJRW8f.png. Your snippet is quite clearly broken too: `"message": "Script error.",`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this:

```
var msj = bootbox.alert("Error message.");
$('#Barcode').val('');
msj.on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {
    $('#Barcode').focus();    
});
```

Using this you're going to focus the input after the modal is hidden/closed.